# Connect to node,js server from another site

Tags: node.js, request

Is there a way to have express server on www.server.com, and connect to that by going to www.page.com?
I mean im going to page.com, it requests for "/", and the server on server.com response with index.html to page.com

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Configure the DNS for `www.page.com` to point to the same IP address as the DNS for `www.server.com`
2. Port forward from port 80 on the ip address `www.page.com` points to to the ip address `www.server.com` points to
3. Run a reverse proxy on port 80 on the ip address `www.page.com` points to to `www.server.com` (e.g. with [Apache HTTPD & Proxypagee](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass))

Option 3 is the only one of those which would work if the Express server pays attention to the Host request header.

Comment: So i f i want to request for /home /panel etc i need to use 3rd option?

Comment: @RafałMichałuszek — No. The path has nothing to do with the Host header.